# How to make "golden fingers" in EDA tools?

Tags: pcb-design

I'm trying to elongate the Raspberry Pi 15-pin MIPI-CSI port using an HDMI line, so I need to make a simple FPC board that has a HDMI connector on one side, and another side with 15 "golden fingers" to connect with the RPi (possibly several extra pads to weld with GPIO).

According to my knowledge, I have to use some schematic tool to create the logical layout of the circuit, then use some PCB tool to realize the logical layout into physical geometry.

I have a problem: there are HDMI items in the schematics library, but no "golden fingers" or "pads". Although there are "generic" connectors, how could I make the PCB tool know they should be treated as "golden fingers"?

Comment: But you can't have a standard PCB that inserts to FPC connector. Unless it's s flexible PCB. It might be best to have a board with FPC connector which will connect via FPC cable. However it is an extremely bad idea to reuse a cable that has a specific purpose to a custom purpose. You or someone else may damage expensive equipment by plugging your non-HDMI gear to HDMI gear.

Comment: @Justme Yes, I 'm going to place the HDMI adapter directly on an FPC board. I'm only using it on my personal project, not for any formal use.